# Highcharts problems with animation of column chart

Tags: javascript, animation, highcharts

I am using Highcharts and want to make column chart that has nice animation when data changes. Animation has to be such that existing columns change their height.

I created a fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/Martinsos/Z2L6b/), where Method 3 does animation that I want, but does not work when there are many columns (they just blink instead of animate).

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
<button id="button1">Method 1</button>
<button id="button2">Method 2</button>
<button id="button3">Method 3</button>
```

_

```
$(function () {
    var getRandomData = function(size, addition) {
        if (!addition) addition = 5;
        var data = [];
        var len = Math.random() * size + addition;
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            data.push(Math.random() * 50);
        }
        return data;
    };

    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
                type: 'column',
            },
        series: [{
            data: getRandomData(100)
        }]
    });

    $('#button1').click(function() {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

        chart.series[0].setData(getRandomData(100), false); // No animation happens

        chart.redraw();
    });

    $('#button2').click(function() {
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();

        chart.series[0].remove();
        chart.addSeries({data: getRandomData(100)}); // Animation happens, but not the kind     I want

        chart.redraw();
    });

    var method3 = function(chart, size, addition) {
        var series = chart.series[0];
        var data = getRandomData(size, addition);
        var seriesLen = series.data.length;
        $.each(data, function(index, newPoint) {
            if (index < seriesLen) {
                series.data[index].update(newPoint, false);
            } else {
                series.addPoint([index, newPoint], false);
            }
        });
        while (seriesLen > data.length) {
            series.data[seriesLen-1].remove(false);
            seriesLen--;
        }

        chart.redraw();
    };

    $('#button3').click(function() { // Works as I want it
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        method3(chart, 100);
        chart.redraw();
    });

    $('#button4').click(function() { // Fails for large chart
        var chart = $('#container').highcharts();
        method3(chart, 100, 500);
        chart.redraw();
    });
});
```

How can I make that animation work always, even for large amount of columns?
I also have similar problem with line charts: if they have more then about 200 hundred points and I do setData on multiple series and then redraw, they sometimes just blink instead of animating. How can I solve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunaltey setData has no this kind of animation, but you can destroy series and add new one.

```
 $('#update').click(function () {

        chart.series[0].remove();
        chart.addSeries({
            data:  [5, 4, 2, 2, 14, 5, 3, 2, 1, 2]
        });
 });
```

See simple exmaple: 
http://jsfiddle.net/2CdVr/

Comment: That is ok, but that is not the type of animation I want. As I said in my fiddle, what I want is 'transition' animation.

Comment: But as I see you have http://jsfiddle.net/LKLDz whcih doesnt work with many columns, as you said, so I introduced a workaournd for that, which seems work.

Comment: Have you tried to use addPoint instead of setData() ?

Comment: Yes, take a look at fiddle please, it is method 3

Comment: Unfortunately it all what highcharts has included.

Comment: Do you have any idea why animation does not work for large charts? Both for column and line/spline

Comment: Do you @Sebastian have any idea why animatino works for small charts but not for large? Am I doing something wrong or is it Highcharts limitation?